# HttpResponseRedirect with Dajaxice

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, dajaxice

I have a Dajaxice view that checks to see if there is a particular item in a shopping cart before adding a new one. In my line of work, certain items require certain prerequisites, and it's really hard to process multiple items with the same prerequisites. If that doesn't make sense, it doesn't really matter that much.

When the Dajaxice view returns, it sends a value( 1 if everything was validated correctly, 0 if not. ). The javascript function that processes it looks like this:

```
function mta_limit(data) {
    if (data.good == 1) {
        document.forms['shopping_cart'].submit();
    } else {
        alert("Sorry! Only one of those items per order.");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is if any computer savvy person sees that code, they can very easily circumnavigate the AJAX check and put anything they want in their order.

Is there a way to sumbit the form in Dajaxice? I've tried HttpResponseRedirect with no avail.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as submitting a form always adds a new order, you'll be vulnerable to a savvy user circumventing your checks. So getting the Dajaxice view to literally "submit the form" won't solve your problem.

What you could do is:

1. Have your Dajaxice view update your shopping cart model and then update the display of that model on the page in some way.
2. Do a final form validation check on submit to make sure your rules are being followed.